# Audio file bandwidth limitation

Tags: audio, bandwidth

I am new to audio file processing. I want to limit the bandwidth of some audio files. The problem is that all the solutions that I find online suggest to limit the sample rate. Is there a way to limit the bandwidth of an audio file, without changing the sample rate?

Comment: Yes, it's called *filtering* - just apply a suitable low-pass filter.

Answer (score -1):

If audio file is not compressed format (WAV,AIFF,AU), sampling rate is bandwidth (44.1Khz = 44100 Bytes/sec)
but compressed format, Bitrate is bandwidth, re-encode it for changing bandwidth.